# A word for my tech stuff

Tags: word-choice

I am looking for a one word definition of all the tech stuff we use in our everyday life. PC, iPad,  cell phone, MP3 etc.

When I am on a trip I always want to have my....with me!!

Comment: There are many words, I'm sure but *tech* and *gadgetry* or *gadgets* would all fit.

Comment: I call it my gadgets or paraphernalia or gizmos or appurtenance.

Comment: "When I am on a trip I always want to have my <i>digital life</i> with me"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the two most common terms for all of this are simply **electronics** and **technology**.

You could also say that I want to bring all of my **gadgets/gizmos/devices**.

> Usage:
>
> - I can't live without my technology.
> - I got two bags from the airport but still missing the one with all my electronics.
> - I have so many gadgets that some seem to be redundant.
> - I have chords for all my gizmos all tangled up.
> - I have a case for each of my devices.

Just to my ear gadget and gizmo seem smaller.  I would have a hard time labeling a big laptop as a gadget or gizmo but could probably call a laptop a device.  If I was talking about my PC, my 3 Ipads, my MP3 player, my headphones, and so on... then I would probably say my technology or electronics although I guess devices might still work.

Answer (score 0):

First word that comes to mind is "Apparatus"

> device, gadget, gear, tackle, kit, contraption, machine, tool
>   system, method, mechanism, arrangement, organization, operation, machinery

When I am on a trip I always want to have my
 **apparatus** with me!